# Benefit to purchasing a license for sublime text?

Tags: sublime-text-3, sublime-text

I'm currently using Sublime Text 3 as my primary coding application. I've noticed that after (say, 25, I really have no idea) files saves there is a notification about purchasing a license for Sublime Text 3.

Is there any real benefit to purchasing a license, other than removing this little prompt every couple hours?

Comment: sure. you get to feel warm and fuzzy inside.

Answer (score 22):

To clarify purchasing a license is not "upgrading" to a pro version. It is purchasing the product which you have been using the trial period on.

Primary benefits:

1. Access to the developer version (since it requires a license key)
2. Getting rid of the prompt.
3. Supporting further development
4. Not stealing a commercial product.

   I know you can use it forever without paying for it, but it is **not free software**.
   The trial period is there just for that, to let you try it before plunking down your cash.